# How to properly realloc a bit array in C

Tags: c, bitmap, bit, realloc, bitarray

I'm trying to grow the array of bits dynamically as more values are entered. I'm having two issues so far. I gdb'd into it and I can't really see what part I'm missing while reallocing the bit array, here are the issues I see:

1. Valgrind reports several Invalid Reads/Writes
2. The total bit count is 968 instead of 999 (I assume it's related to #1)

---

```
==109614== Invalid read of size 4
==109614==    at 0x10926F: get_bit (a.c:26)
==109614==    by 0x1093EF: main (a.c:56)
==109614==  Address 0x4a27094 is 0 bytes after a block of size 4 alloc'd
==109614==    at 0x483BB65: calloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:762)
==109614==    by 0x1092C8: init (a.c:32)
==109614==    by 0x10939A: main (a.c:50)
==109614== 
==109614== Invalid read of size 4
==109614==    at 0x1091A6: set_bit (a.c:18)
==109614==    by 0x109407: main (a.c:57)
==109614==  Address 0x4a27094 is 0 bytes after a block of size 4 alloc'd
==109614==    at 0x483BB65: calloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:762)
==109614==    by 0x1092C8: init (a.c:32)
==109614==    by 0x10939A: main (a.c:50)
==109614== 
==109614== Invalid write of size 4
==109614==    at 0x1091D9: set_bit (a.c:18)
==109614==    by 0x109407: main (a.c:57)
==109614==  Address 0x4a27094 is 0 bytes after a block of size 4 alloc'd
==109614==    at 0x483BB65: calloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:762)
==109614==    by 0x1092C8: init (a.c:32)
==109614==    by 0x10939A: main (a.c:50)
==109614== 
val=999
total bits set=968
..
```

---

```
#include <limits.h>    /* for CHAR_BIT */
#include <string.h>
#include <stdint.h>   /* for uint32_t */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef uint32_t word_t; // I want to change this, from uint32_t to uint64_t
enum { BITS_PER_WORD = sizeof(word_t) * CHAR_BIT };
#define WORD_OFFSET(b) ((b) / BITS_PER_WORD)
#define BIT_OFFSET(b)  ((b) % BITS_PER_WORD)

typedef struct bm_ {
  word_t *bmp;
  int size;
} bm;

void set_bit(word_t *words, int n) {
  words[WORD_OFFSET(n)] |= ((word_t)1 << BIT_OFFSET(n));
}

void clear_bit(word_t *words, int n) {
  words[WORD_OFFSET(n)] &= ~((word_t)1 << BIT_OFFSET(n));
}

int get_bit(word_t *words, int n) {
  word_t bit = words[WORD_OFFSET(n)] & ((word_t)1 << BIT_OFFSET(n));
  return bit != 0;
}

bm *init(uint32_t s) {
  bm *bim = calloc(1, sizeof(bm));
  bim->bmp = calloc(s, sizeof(word_t));
  bim->size = s;
  return bim;
}

uint32_t calc(uint32_t i) {
  return (((i) + (BITS_PER_WORD)-1) / (BITS_PER_WORD));
}

int mrealloc (bm *b, int bits) {
  int more = calc(bits);
  uint32_t *t = realloc (b->bmp, more * sizeof(word_t));
  memset (t + b->size, 0, (more - b->size) * sizeof(word_t));
  b->bmp = t;
  b->size = more;
}

int main(){
  bm *b = init(1);
  uint32_t i = 1, val = 0, cnt = 0;
  for (i = 1; i < 1000; i++) {
    val = i;
    uint32_t bytes = calc(val);
    if(bytes <= b->size) {
      if(!get_bit(b->bmp, val))
        set_bit(b->bmp, val);
    }else{
      mrealloc(b, val);
      set_bit(b->bmp, val);
    }
  }
  printf("val=%d\n",val);

  for (uint32_t j=0; j < b->size; j++)
    cnt+=__builtin_popcount(b->bmp[j]);
  printf("total bits set=%d\n",cnt);

  free (b->bmp);
  free (b);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `memset (t + b->size, 0, more - b->size);` Shouldn't that be `memset (t + b->size, 0, (more - b->size) * sizeof(word_t));`?

Comment: Also, `calc()` is completely ignoring the abstraction and hardcoding `32`.

Comment: @kaylum thank you, that does help. though still get a few invalid read/writes

Comment: @unwind Thanks for the heads up, code updated.

Comment: Unclear why `bim->size = s;` in `init()` (no round up of size), yet  `b->size = more;` (round -ed up size) in `mrealloc()` and why go through `int`?

Comment: `int mrealloc (bm *b, int bits) {   ...   b->size = more;}` implies you are not fully enabling warnings.  (missing return)  Save us all time.  Enable all warnings.

Comment: `memset (t + b->size, 0, (more - b->size) * sizeof(word_t));` is certainly a problem if `more < b->size`.  I guess code is lucky it appears to not have been called that way.

Comment: @chux Thanks a lot for all the comments, I've taken notes about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Out of index range attempt - and code does not check index.

```
mrealloc(b, val);
set_bit(b->bmp, val);  // 1 passed end
```

I think OP wanted

```
mrealloc(b, val);
set_bit(b->bmp, val-1);
```

Comment: You are right, that `val - 1` did the trick. Thanks a lot! BTW, it means also that `get_bit` should be also - 1